# Неверно работает условие или цикл

Tags: python, циклы, условия

Помогите найти ошибку. Задание: Создайте цикл проверки введенных пользователем логина и пароля на соответствие следующим установленным правилам:

- Логин должен содержать ровно две заглавные буквы и состоять минимум из 6 символов.
- Пароль должен содержать ровно одну заглавную букву, хотя бы одну цифру и состоять минимум из 8 символов.

Если логин / пароль соответствует требованиям, должно выводиться сообщение: "Логин соответствует условиям регистрации" / "Пароль соответствует условиям регистрации". В противном случае выводится сообщение "Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации" или "Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации" соответственно для логина и пароля.

Если и логин, и пароль правильные, то выводится фраза "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Добро пожаловать в MangoFM". Цикл завершается. В ином случае на экране пишется "К сожалению, условия не выполнены, попробуйте еще раз" и у пользователя снова запрашивают логин и пароль.
Мой код:

```
login = input("Введите логин: ")
password = input("Введите пароль: ")

while True:
    uppercase_letters = 0
    digits = 0
    if len(login) >= 6:
        for char in login:
            if char.isupper():
                uppercase_letters += 1
        if uppercase_letters == 2:
            print("Логин соответствует условиям регистрации")
        else:
            print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")
    else:
        print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")
    if len(password) >= 8:
        for char in password:
            if char.isupper():
                uppercase_letters += 1
            elif char.isdigit():
                digits += 1
        if uppercase_letters == 1 and digits >= 1:
            print("Пароль соответствует условиям регистрации")
            print("Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Добро пожаловать в MangoFM")
            break
        else:
            print("Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации")
    else:
        print("Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации")

    print("К сожалению, условия не выполнены, попробуйте еще раз")
```

Не проходит проверка именно пароля по условиям задачи. Где ошибка?

Новый код:

```
def check_login(login):
    uppercase_letters = 0
    if len(login) >= 6:
        for char in login:
            if char.isupper():
                uppercase_letters += 1
        if uppercase_letters == 2:
            print("Логин соответствует условиям регистрации")
            return True
        else:
            print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")
    else:
        print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")
        return False

def check_password(password):
    uppercase_letters = 0
    digits = 0
    if len(password) >= 8:
        for char in password:
            if char.isupper():
                uppercase_letters += 1
            elif char.isdigit():
                digits += 1
        if uppercase_letters == 1 and digits >= 1:
            print("Пароль соответствует условиям регистрации")
            return True
        else:
            print("Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации")
            return False
    else:
        print("Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации")
    return False

while True:
    login = input("Введите логин: ")
    password = input("Введите пароль: ")

    if check_login(login) and check_password(password):
        print("Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Добро пожаловать в MangoFM")
        break
    else:
        print("К сожалению, условия не выполнены, попробуйте еще раз")
```

В новом коде не выводится запись про неверный пароль. Например, логин верный, а пароль нет. На выводе получается "Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации" и "К сожалению, условия не выполнены, попробуйте еще раз". Ошибка в отрезке кода, где идет проверка пароля, если он равен или более 8 символов. Если пароль не подходит под это условие, то выводится сообщение о его неверном вводе. Почему про пароль нет вывода?

Comment: Такой код очень сложно понять и невозможно поддерживать в дальнейшем. Учитесь делать рефакторинг, выделять логически связанные блоки кода в отдельные функции. Я бы каждую проверку в отдельную функцию выделил, проще говоря. А в основном коде проверял бы результаты работы этих функций.

Comment: Если у вас новый вопрос по новому коду, то задайте новый вопрос, а не редактируйте старый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не обнуляете `uppercase_letters` перед обработкой пароля

Для того, чтобы при плохом логине и хорошем пароле не было сообщения об успешной регистрации, можно добавить `continue` после двух сообщений `print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")`.

Кроме того, по логике ввод логина и пароля нужно внести внутрь цикла `while`, в начало

```
while True:
    login = input("Введите логин: ")
    password = input("Введите пароль: ")
    uppercase_letters = 0
    digits = 0
    if len(login) >= 6:
        for char in login:
            if char.isupper():
                uppercase_letters += 1
        if uppercase_letters == 2:
            print("Логин соответствует условиям регистрации")
        else:
            print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")
            continue
    else:
        print("Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации")
        continue
    uppercase_letters = 0
    if len(password) >= 8:
        for char in password:
            if char.isupper():
                uppercase_letters += 1
            elif char.isdigit():
                digits += 1
        if uppercase_letters == 1 and digits >= 1:
            print("Пароль соответствует условиям регистрации")
            print("Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Добро пожаловать в MangoFM")
            break
        else:
            print("Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации")
    else:
        print("Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации")

    print("К сожалению, условия не выполнены, попробуйте еще раз")
```

Comment: А вот были бы проверки в отдельных функциях... ))

Comment: @MBo, еще заметила, что если логин НЕ прошел проверку, а пароль прошел, то в любом случае выводится сообщение об успешной регистрации. Можете тут подсказать причину? Точнее не причину, а как это исправить? Пока делаю без функции.

Comment: @Tory потому что вывод текста об успешной регистрации завязан только на проверку пароля и с проверкой логина никак не связан.

Comment: @Эникейщик, это я поняла) а как соединить эти 2 проверки? Вот примерно должно быть на выходе: Выходные данные:

Логин не соответствует условиям регистрации
Пароль не соответствует условиям регистрации
К сожалению, условия не выполнены, попробуйте еще раз
Логин соответствует условиям регистрации
Пароль соответствует условиям регистрации
Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Добро пожаловать в MangoFM

Comment: @Tory Ну я вам показал, как при неверном логине возвращаться к его вводу. Но правильнее будет структурировать - вызвали функцию проверки логина, запомнили результат. Вызвали функцию проверки пароля - запомнили результат. Причем функция одна и та же, только параметры длины и количества нужных символов разные. После этого анализируете результаты и выводите сообщения.

Comment: @MBo, спасибо, буду пробовать